# Efficient Concatenation of Large Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, memory, data-science

I'm running a process that creates a very large number of feature vectors (as numpy arrays) and stacks them into a single array. This process is currently very memory intensive and I'm looking for a more memory efficient way to run it.

Currently I generate feature vectors in batches of 100000 and concatenate them together.

```
all_features = None

for i in range(0, num_entries, 100000):
    features = get_features(entries[i:i+100000]) # generate a batch of 100,000 feature vectors
    features = np.array(features)

    if all_features is not None:
        all_features = np.concatenate([all_features, features])
    else:
        all_features = features

    del features
    gc.collect()
```

I've found that iteratively concatenating feature vectors, then deleting the intermediate `features` object is more memory efficient than generating all features at once and concatenating them all at once. I believe this is because `np.concatenate` allocates a new object in memory. (Trying to generate all feature vectors at once, then concatenating blows up memory).

That said, it gets to a point where running the concatenation near the end of the loop still requires about 30 GB of memory (which is immediately freed after the concatenation is run).

Basically I have enough memory on my instance to store the full feature set, but the memory jumps from packing things into a single array make me run out of memory.

Is there a more memory efficient way of running this?

Comment: Since you are working with large batches, most of the intuitions we develop from small test cases don't apply.  I'm not going to test anything that pushes the time and memory limits of my machine (at least not willingly).

Answer (score 1):

If total size of all_features is known, I'd suggest to allocate it in advance `all_features=np.zeros(...)` and then populate it in the loop. Thus you get rid of multiple reallocations, deletions and np.concatenate() calls.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `get_features` function a generator and then use `np.fromiter` to create the array.

#### Simple Example

```py
def gen_values():
    for i in range(1000000): 
        yield i

a = np.fromiter(gen_values(), dtype=int)
```

You need to specify the `dtype` in `np.fromiter` and you can optionaly specify the number of elements to get from the generator with `count`. While it is optional, it is much better to specify `count` such that numpy can pre-allocate the output array, instead of resizing it on demand.

Comment: This only works if `gen_values()` produces one number at at time. The OP is talking about generating 1000's of 'feature vectors'.  Think of it as combining many 2d arrays.